# Is there a way to create Handlebars partial calls dynamically in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to build a PDF-file with puppeteer headless chrome and handlebarjs for my templating.

I tried using the #each from handlebarsjs like

```html
{{#each item as |image|}}
    {{#each child as |childImage|}} 
    <div>{{> (fillImage childImage)}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

My helper function looks like this

```
handlebars.registerHelper("fillImage", function (image) {
  return image;
});
```

I register my partials dynamically like this

```
for (let index = 0; index < max; index++) {
handlebars.registerPartial(`image${index},<img src= ${some image base64 encoded}`>
)}
```

**I want it to call for n partials that will be loaded into the PDF like**

```html
{{> image0}}
{{> image1}}
{{> image2}}
{{> image3}}
...
{{> imagen}}
```

**How can I do that?**

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: @Vaviloff how can I display an unknown number of images in my PDF where each picture is in it's own partial?